# Is there any Lockout feature in Web API ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I've been using ASP.NET Identity for manage user. In sign-in function, we can tell ASP.NET that user must be locked after several failed Sign-In attempt.

```
// To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

Since we have `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs`, can we do the same as above when trying to get Token from API? I mean user must be locked too after several failed Get Token attempt.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
...
}
```

If it's possible, please tell me how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This could help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212716/web-api-2-and-asp-identity-handling-of-locked-out-users

Comment: Yep, I did it last year. Manually check the field in AspNetUsers which indicates that user already locked and return failure. @AnandMurali

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207769/5675763. it was useful for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API 2 and ASP Identity - Handling of locked out users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212716/web-api-2-and-asp-identity-handling-of-locked-out-users)

Comment: just check user.LockoutEndDateUtc != null && user.LockoutEndDateUtc > DateTime.Now in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials